# Show div under clicked element aligned right

Tags: jquery, css

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7142075/1970715) i got different popup divs for every button but i want them to be aligned on the right side of the clicked button.

[image]

Changing the

> left: btn.offset().left

doesn't get me anywhere.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1, #button2").click(function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var clickedId = $(this).attr("id");
    var clickedPopup = "_popup";
    $("#" + clickedId + clickedPopup).css({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: btn.offset().top + btn.outerHeight() + 10,
      left: btn.offset().left
    }).slideToggle('');
  });
});
```

```css
.button_div,
.text_div {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#button1_popup,
#button2_popup {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 220px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text_div">div with unknown width</div>
<div id="button1" class="button_div"><button id="one">One</button></div>
<div id="button2" class="button_div"><button id="two">Two</button></div>
<div id="button1_popup">Message with some text</div>
<div id="button2_popup">Message with some text</div>
```

Comment: Works for me, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do this in javascript when css works perfectly well. I suggest nesting the hidden divs inside the `.button_div`s, and `position`ing them `absolute`ly with `right:0` as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1, #button2").click(function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var clickedId = $(this).attr("id");
    var clickedPopup = "_popup";
    $("#" + clickedId + clickedPopup).slideToggle('');
  });
});
```

```css
.button_div,
.text_div {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#button1_popup,
#button2_popup {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 220px;
  height: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text_div">div with unknown width</div>
<div id="button1" class="button_div">
  <button id="one">One</button>
  <div id="button1_popup">Message with some text</div>
</div>
<div id="button2" class="button_div">
  <button id="two">Two</button>
  <div id="button2_popup">Message with some text</div>
</div>
```